# Is it possible to generate assemblies selectively?

Tags: maven-2

My pom.xml is used to generate around 8 assemblies.So, when i run mvn assembly:assembly, all are generated.Is there a way to selectively generate 1/2 assemblies at a time?

Answer (score 5):

You can put the assemblies into [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), so they'll only be generated when the owning profile is activated. You have various options for activating the profile based on the presence or value of properties or files. You can group more then one assembly into a profile if you will always generate them together.

Answer (score 0):

We use one project per assembly, each has a dedicated pom (possibly with parent pom...).

```
    >mvn clean install
```

This is the command we use, that creates the assemblies.

- In the parent directory (and pom), it will **build all**.
- In a subdirectory, it will **build the current assembly**, and possibly sub-ones.